# Encrypting Linux LPD to Windows (ipsec/ssh tunnel/other)

Tags: encryption, ssh-tunneling, cups, ipsec

I have a Windows print server running LPD.  My Linux clients are all configured to point to a separate Linux server running Cups (TCP 631), and then the Cups config points to an LPD URI which directs them back to the Windows box (TCP 515 I believe).  I have to use LPD instead of IPP because of some proprietary print software that we use in this setup.

I want to encrypt the print traffic going from the Linux Cups server to the Windows Print server.  Reading about ipsec has made my eyes glaze over a bit, and I have concerns about the implementation differences from Windows to Linux (I think it needs to be configured on both ends, but maybe not). Also, I want what is essentially transport layer security, endpoint to endpoint, not every IP packet encrypted, only LPD print traffic. An SSH Tunnel seems simpler, but I would have to install SSH server software on the Windows box, which is a drag.  Anyone have experience or suggestions in this scenario?

Comment: Sounds like a use case for a VPN.

Comment: I am leaning towards an SSH tunnel with the server being the Windows box, tunneling to Windows' TCP port 515 from the Linux box